# What is the best place to store my data?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, sdk

I'm newbie in iOS development and I have a question.
I have a some data received from the Internet(it is XML files) and I want to create from this files one big file and store it in some place on the disk, but I don't know exactly where. 
What is the best way to store such data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save it in your document directory.

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

Or if you have enabled itunes filesharing support and don't want the user to access your file, save it in your library directory

```
NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```